# Prescription glasses curved design

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

Typically, prescription glasses are built with a pair of lenses oriented in a straight line with very little deviation from 180° angle (Figure **1(a)**). However, protective or sport goggles (no dioptres) are often curved and overall more ergonomic.

Is it possible to design more ergonomic prescription glasses that would follow a curvature of an axial cross-section of a human skull (Figure **1(b)**)? If not, what are the physical limitations here?

[image]

Figure **1**. MRI head scan, axial section (top view). Red color denotes the shape of the glasses, blue dashed line – curvature. **(a)** – conventional design; **(b)** – curved design.

Comment: > *"design more ergonomic prescription glasses"* this refers to design and ergonomy, possibly engineering, but I do not see any physics in the question.

Comment: @JánLalinský I thought physics is in obtaining the proper, undistorted image in the focal plane when both planes and optical axes are *not* parallel for the pair of eyes. Yes, there is engineering involved, but first of all I'm interested in whether optics allows for building optical paths for the lenses  "angled" to the eyes.

Comment: My glasses for myopia are of the kind pictured on figure b), and their corrective function works well for objects seen up to 45 degrees horizontally off the main line of sight (with one eye only). But back to the meta-issue, even given your comment, that is too general concern. I still do not think the question phrasing rises any specific physics problem of general interest. It is a vague optics engineering/design question, without any your attempt to solve it. Perhaps if you phrased the physics problem in detail that you think there is, then the question would attract more positive reception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to project an image from one side of a magnifying glass to the other, assuming that you want a clear image, you need to have the magnifying glass perpendicular to the light rays coming from the image.   Same thing with the image projected to the retina of your eyes. The lens needs to be perpendicular to your line of sight. Because the lines of sight of the two eyes are virtually parallel, the lens will have to be on the same line/plane like in your figure a.
Wearing contact lenses might be an *ergonomic* solution?

Edit:
Seems like I was wrong. [*Walmart*](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Safety-Vu-Bifocal-Safety-Glasses/39248774?athcpid=39248774&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=PWVAV&athieid=v0&athstid=CS020&athguid=4ab7c28a-5bd-1680a176df7976&athena=true) sells something very similar to what you are looking for.
  [image: bifocal safety glasses]
 I have no idea how they did it. Good question